# Archiving large folders

Tags: compression, archiving, file-format

I'd like to create a (compressed) archive of a folder which contains ~350,000 items totalling ~17 GB.

Is `.tar.gz` a sane format to use, or would `.zip`, `.rar`, or `.7z` work better for handling that much data and that many files?

---

***Edit:*** just came across [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/5230/which-archive-compression-format); it looks like `7-zip` (with `bzip2` compression) is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you are wanting to access the archived files.

If you are only ever going to restore *all* the files in one go, then tar + a compression system (gzip, bzip2, xz, whatever) will be fine and will probably give you the best compression.

If you will want to extract a subset of the files at any point then stay away from tar.  Tar has no central index of the contents, and so will have to read through the *entire* archive to extract the few files you want.  In this situation something like ZIP or RAR would be much more sensible.

Comment: This is just a basic backup in case I screw something up while upgrading an old Linux install, so indexed content is probably a Good Thing for this use case. Is 7z also indexed (I can only imagine the answer is "yes")? Any idea of which format will be faster to build?

Comment: ZIP and 7z are both pretty similar technologies (7z is a super-set of ZIP) and both are indexed.  Most of the time taken will be disk access, so there won't be much to choose between them speed wise.

Comment: "stay away from tar" - not quite so. With `pixz`-made archives (archive.tar.xz) you can easily extract just a single file.

Comment: No you can't.  Tar is a tape stream format, xz is a compression algorithm. You have to decompress the xz stream whilst streaming the tar data until you reach the file. There is no way of "jumping in" and just decompressing the one file like you can with things like Zip, where each file is compressed individually.